# query including an IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I want my query to using a IF statement, identify; if the current `num_unmarked` will become 0 after this update, then also set `is final` to 'YES'.

so here is my query:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE results_tb 
                    SET 
                        num_unmarked = num_unmarked - 1,
                        is_final=IF( num_unmarked-1=0, 'YES', is_final ),
                        score = score + $awarded
                    WHERE 
                        user_id = $student 
                    AND 
                        test_id = $test 
            ";
```

what is actually happening is, the query runs, num_unmarked decrements and score is updated however even if num_unmarked is 1 (not 0) it still sets is_final to 'YES'.

could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong please or enlighten me to a better way? (i am nooby :D)

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updates are processed sequentially in MySql, so the update to `num_unmarked` occurs before the `IF` statement, and the `IF` statement uses the newly updated value.  So you actually want to use the value as if it has already been updated, i.e., compare it directly to 0:

```
is_final = IF(num_unmarked=0, 'YES', is_final),
```